# Creating table with the same name as CSV

Tags: mysql

I have a huge csv file with a huge number of columns (around 1000).
Is there any way in mysql by which i can create a table with column name same as in first row in csv.
Example:- Suppose my csv is somewhat like this.

```
"id","name"
"1","x"
"2","y"
"3","z"
```

Now out of this i want to create a table with columns `(id and name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a tool? [SQLYog](https://www.webyog.com/) is your friend.

Have a look at: [What's the easiest way to import a new table into MySQL v5 from CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156994/whats-the-easiest-way-to-import-a-new-table-into-mysql-v5-from-csv)

Comment: I will have a look at it and come back to you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns = ['id', 'name']; // get column names from csv
$sql     = 'CREATE TABLE table_name (';

foreach ($columns as $name) {
    $sql .= $name . ' varchar(255) NOT NULL'
}

$sql .= ')';
```

Comment: Ok but i don't want to specify the name of the columns in my query or procedure as it is in huge number. Can we do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), create an new table with just an ID field, and import the data from your CSV, then remove the data if you just want an empty table.

[image]